# MySQL InnoDB: locking the destination of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, locking, innodb

When I add a row that references another table (in a transaction), MySQL seems to lock the whole row that's being referenced. This prevents updates of other columns in the destination table that should be able to run concurrently without any problem.

Simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `foo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `foo` (`foo`),
  CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo`) REFERENCES `t1` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES (1,1),(2,0),(3,4);
```

Task A:

```
BEGIN;
insert into bar(foo) values(2);
-- now we ask task B to do some work for us
```

Task B:

```
-- when triggered by Task A, tries to do this:
update t1 set num=num+1 where id=2;
-- does not complete because it waits for the lock
```

Any ideas how to avoid this deadlock? Task A should only read-lock the single value which it actually refers to, so Task B couldn't renumber or delete `t1[id=2].id` but would otherwise be free to update that row. Is it possible to convince MySQL to do this?

Splitting t1 into two linked tables (one for Task A to refer to and one for task B to update) would result in a heap of fairly intrusive refactoring.

Joining the tasks is not an option because B's work changes global state, thus must be able to commit even if A fails.

Switching to Postgres (which supports this; I checked) is not an easily-executed option.

Answer (score 3):

This is a behavior of MySQL foreign keys that frankly convinces many projects to avoid using foreign key constraints, even though their database logically has foreign key references.

You can't lock just one column of a row. InnoDB effectively locks the whole row against update or delete if an exclusive lock exists on a child row that references it. The idea is that while a child row is depending on that parent row and is in progress of an insert/update/delete, the parent row shouldn't be deleted or its key modified. But you can't lock only the key column that is referenced by the child row.

The best solution is for the transaction against the child table to be finished and committed promptly. The fact that you tried to update the parent row and it timed out (a lock wait timeout is 50 seconds by default) indicates that you have left the transaction running too long.

P.S. What you described is simply a lock-wait. That's not a deadlock. A deadlock is when both transactions end up blocked, waiting for each other to release locks but neither can proceed because they are both waiting. A lock-wait is unidirectional. A deadlock is a cycle of mutual lock-waits.